# If NP is a subset of DTIME[n^O(log n)] then what happens?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np, complexity-classes, nondeterminism

If $\mathsf{NP}\subseteq \mathsf{DTIME}[n^{O(\log n)}]$ then what happens? Does it imply $\mathsf{NP}\neq \mathsf{EXP}$? Is there any other consequences such as $\mathsf{BPP}\neq \mathsf{EXP}$? Does it also give $\mathsf{PSPACE}\subseteq \mathsf{DTIME}[n^{O(\log n)}]$?

Comment: "Does it imply $\textbf{NP} \neq \textbf{EXP}$?" Yes. This follows from the time hierarchy theorem.

Answer (score 3):

If $\textbf{NP} \subseteq \textbf{DTIME}(n^{O(\log n)})$, then we get $\textbf{P}^\textbf{NP} \subseteq \textbf{P}^{\textbf{DTIME}(n^{O(\log n)})} = \textbf{DTIME}(n^{O (\log n)})$. Continuing this reasoning, the entire polynomial hierarchy $\textbf{PH}$ is contained in $\textbf{DTIME}(n^{O(\log n)})$. By the time hierarchy theorem, $\textbf{DTIME}(n^{O(\log n)})$ is a proper subset of $\textbf{EXP}$ (and even of $\textbf{E} = \textbf{DTIME}(2^{O(n)})$), so $\textbf{PH} \neq \textbf{EXP}$. In particular, we also get $\textbf{NP} \neq \textbf{EXP}$ and $\textbf{BPP} \neq \textbf{EXP}$ because both $\textbf{NP}$ and $\textbf{BPP}$ are in the polynomial hierarchy. For $\textbf{BPP}$ this is not that surprising since we [already suspect it is contained in subexponential time](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~fortnow/papers/bppexp.pdf).

What happens for $\textbf{PSPACE}$? Not much, as long as I'm aware of. We have $\textbf{PH} \subseteq \textbf{PP}$ and $\textbf{PH} \subseteq \textbf{P}^\textbf{#P}$ (by Toda's theorem), but I don't see any direct consequence for $\textbf{PP}$, let alone $\textbf{PSPACE}$.

Comment: @dkaee I would have thought $PP$ would also be in quasipolynomial.

Comment: Why is it so? I am not aware of any reductions from $\mathbf{PP}$ to something below it. We can *approximate* $\#\mathbf{P}$ using $\mathbf{BPP}$ machines with $\mathbf{NP}$ oracle, but that's another story.

Comment: doesn't approximmation give msb?

Comment: Not necessarily. To distinguish $2^n$ from $2^n - 1$ you then need zero error. You could frame it as a promise problem, but then correspondence to the original classes is no longer guaranteed.

Comment: so $PH\subseteq \Sigma_{m}^P$ would be in $DTIME(n^{O(\log n)})$ if $m=O((\log n)^c)$ at any fixed $c>0$ correct?

Comment: I am afraid I am not familiar with $\Sigma^P_m$. Am I correct in thinking it is the generalization of $\Sigma_i \subseteq \mathbf{PH}$ in that $m$ many quantifier alternations are allowed?

Comment: That would be correct. In $PH$ we fix $m$.

Comment: You might tackle your supposition using the reasoning expounded [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37614/quantified-boolean-formulas-with-logarithmic-alternations) (though I would take the arguments there with a grain of salt as there are much formulations on the order of "it seems that (...)" and "informal justification"). AFAIK there hasn't been any previous (peer-reviewed and published) research on $\Sigma_{O(\log n)}^\mathbf{P}$, so discussing it would be potentially off-topic for this site. You could follow up on [cstheory.se].